# Linking object build in sub directory in makefile

Tags: c++, makefile

I am trying to link all object I have build in my makefile during the executable compilation, but I cant seem to automate selecting the build directory.

I have tried:

```
test: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCDIR) $(LIBDIR) $(BUILDDIR)/$^ test.cpp -o test.exe
```

The problem is that `$(BUILDDIR)/$^` only inserts `$(BUILDDIR)` in front of the first object file.

How should I be doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add `$(BUILDDIR)` to all the prerequisites directly in the command, then you can do:

```
test: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCDIR) $(LIBDIR) $(addprefix $(BUILDDIR)/,$^) test.cpp -o test.exe
```

However, setting up make rules this way means you're not tracking dependencies correctly. I think what you actually want is this:

```
test: $(addprefix $(BUILDDIR)/,$(OBJECTS))
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(INCDIR) $(LIBDIR) $^ test.cpp -o test.exe
```

Comment: Awesome. That does it. Although I think I will just define `OBJECTS = $(addprefix $(BUILDDIR)/,$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o))` in that case. Any reason not to do that?

Comment: No reason not to. I think putting it in a separate variable like this is even neater.